# Анонимизация комментария при голосе за закрытие путает новичков

Tags: обсуждение

После [недавних изменений](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release?cb=1) комментарии при голосе за закрытие стали отправляться от имени духа, а не от имени пользователя, который проголосовал. С точки зрения новичков - непонятно что происходит. Какой-то бот придрался к вопросу, говорит, что на него нельзя дать адекватный ответ. И спросить, что ж именно не так, не у кого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть достаточно будет перефразировать эти авто-сообщения из указаний, в предложения - *"**попробуйте** исправить вопрос, чтобы ..."*

Comment: @Kromster может быть. модераторы могут поменять текстовки.

Comment: Подозреваю, что это чтобы лимит комментариев не расходовать.

Comment: Да уж... Если вдуматься, то это принципиальная ошибка (обесчеловечивание ресурса)

Comment: Некоторые комментарии этого бота звучат как нападки... Мне не зашло

Comment: Да, мне тоже так кажется (планировал в чате высказаться, но так и поленился). Принципиальная неустранимая проблема этих комментариев — они не поясняют, что конкретно не так. Хуже того, я регулярно встречаю эти комментарии к вопросам, в которых всё вполне понятно (по крайней мере лично мне)

Comment: @andreymal И без этой проблемы (или точнее в дополнение к), я наблюдаю явление (все никак не соберусь спросить на мете, что с этим делать), что почти одни и те же несколько человек закрывают вполне понятные (не идеального качества, т.е. +1 я им не дам, но часто даже -1 они не заслуживают) и по теме вопросы с формулировкой "невозможно дать объективный ответ", и, самое главное, без комментария, о причине закрытия или о том как улучшить вопрос. На некоторые (в темах, где я разбираюсь) абсолютно точно есть объективный ответ.

Comment: @RomanKonoval ну на это проще повлиять - гребсти очередь на закрытие, и жать на таких вопросах "оставить открытым". ну или отвечать до того, как закрыли.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, с этим кагбэ и не надо ничего делать - если сообщество решит что дать объективный ответ невозможно, значит реально есть какая-то проблема с достаточностью/качеством вопроса (другими словами: один участник может не видеть той двусмысленности, которую видят 5 других участников - и это нормально... как и то, что подобные решения принимаются коллективно, а не индивидуально). Плюс, наличие голосов за закрытие, как и само закрытие - еще не приговор вопросу, его можно "вернуть" при необходимости (да, сложно, но все-таки можно. Как минимум, теоретически).

Comment: @yar85 Так главная проблема в том, что не ясно, почему считают, что нельзя дать объективный ответ, комментарий то не оставляют. Если вопрос задает новичок, то с его точки зрения это просто грубо и недружелюбно. Как улучшить вопрос - неясно.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, это да, уточняющие комменты в таких случаях всяко нужны. А то без них получается что сообщество отвечает неоднозначностью своих требований на неоднозначность вопроса - а это, пардон, почти лицемерие (или даже не почти... как посмотреть :)). Я вообще за то чтобы обязать комментом голоса за закрытие: т.е., либо выбираем из списка уже оставленных комментариев (как сейчас работает "другая причина", последняя в списке специфичных) - либо пишем свой вариант... но даже выдвигать такое предложение имхо смысла нет, т.к. то что отсутствует на enSO не имеет шансов быть реализованным тут.

Comment: @PashaPash непонятен момент " гребсти очередь на закрытие, и жать на таких вопросах "оставить открытым" - это значит всю очередь перегребать что ли, пока вопрос не попадется? Да и не факт, что попадется. Мне еще в очереди непринятых правок ни разу не попадался вопрос, у которого есть непринятая правка, и который открыт прямо вот здесь в соседней вкладке.

Comment: @Эникейщик нет, это значит что нужно гребсти очередь и на **всех** вопросах, заслуживающих "остаться открытыми" жать "оставить открытым". Потому что сейчас закрывашки, фактически, победили - я вчера погреб минут 15, закрывают все подряд, вообще не вчитываясь в вопросы.

Comment: @Эникейщик можете для интереса открыть историю (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history), и посмотреть, на чем голосуют за закрытие. там полно нормальных вопросов, но вахтерство зашкаливает

Comment: @PashaPash да, да,  я давно заметил что закрытие вопросов это больше про **"психологию маленьких эгоистов"**  чем про **"вопросы"** . _Жена не дала , ребенок нагрубил , всЁ я побежал закрывать вопросы на "переполненной-стопке" так им гадам !!_