# Отсутствие перевода для комментария Духа о неясности ответа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии, дух-сообщества

Есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1327735/238742), где наблюдается такая картинка. [Здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11687/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) данная тема не поднималась:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ сам по себе в данном контексте роли не играет. Как я вижу, комментарий духа не переведён.

Comment: Интересно, в чью голову вообще пришла идея давать комментарии от робота?

Comment: @avp комментарии всё же не от робота, но от лица робота.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, хотите сказать, что это один из предопределенных комментариев, который выбран руками каким-то человеком? Зачем его делать от лица робота?

Comment: @avp чтобы не тормошить проверяющего, я думаю. Вообще, [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11707/176217) речь о том же по сути.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ага, я читал, там еще комментариев добавили. imho это серьезная проблема. По хорошему, в подобных случаях обязательно должна быть не отписка, а настоящий комментарий от конкретного участника, с которым хотя бы теоретически можно было бы общаться

Comment: @avp, да общение помогло бы, юзер из примера пытался общаться, но ответа не получил )

Comment: @avp это уже почти из оперы [комментировать каждый минус](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/176217), кмк.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, иногда мне кажется, что это (комментировать минусы) было бы хорошим начинанием

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. - [В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста нажмите [править] чтобы добавить больше информации, которая поможет другим понять, как это отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справка]($url$)](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16913)

не уверен по поводу `справки`, правильно ли я понял как это называется и по поводу `править` если что могу поправить как нужно.

P.S. Что-то traducir меня удивил (текст не переносится):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного подправил, утвердил.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спс :D

Comment: Там ещё `[edit]` надо было оставить как есть, т.к. это ["волшебная ссылка"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/339911). Видно, что она даже на исходном скрине уже переведена оказалась.